# c# delegate array with string & double

Tags: c#, arrays

I got a problem, I'm studying `С#`. I'm begginer then.

I have 1 abstract class `Figure` and 2 classes inherited: `Circle` and `Rectangle`

On each class, I calculate the surface of each figure.

And I have to return `SurfaceTotal = Circle.Surface() + Rectangle.Surface()`

My problem is I need to have this surface with other string values in my array for display them in the console.

See some function to understand it:

From `Figure` :

```
 abstract public double Surface();
```

From `Rectangle` :

```
public override double Surface()
  {
     double resultat = longueur * largeur;  
     return resultat;
  }
```

From `Circle` :

```
public override double Surface()
{
    double resultat = Math.PI * (rayon * rayon);
    return resultat; 
}
```

So I decide to use delegate for it,

```
public delegate string resultat();
```

and then I did this array :

```
resultat[] res = new resultat[4];

            res[0] = new resultat(rectangle.Informations);
            res[1] = new resultat(cercle.Informations);
            res[2] = new resultat(rectangle.Surface);
            res[3] = new resultat(cercle.Surface);
```

And for the display :

```
        Console.WriteLine("Rectangle centré au point  : {0} \n", res[0]());
        Console.WriteLine("Cercle centré au point  : {0} \n", res[1]());
        Console.WriteLine("Surface total   : {0} \n", res[2]() + res[3]());
```

The problem is : in `res[2]` and `res[3]` I have `double` values, but in the other ones I have `strings` values.

So like that, the values aren't added.

And I have to use 1 array, then I wanted added the 2 values before to insert in this array. But I don't know how...
Do you have an idea guys ? 
Thanks

Comment: Your code snippets still have several definitions missing (such as `resultat`).  Can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: Do you mind the declaration of delegate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear why you are using delegates here at all. You could simply use a string array.

```
string[] res = new string[4];
res[0] = rectangle.Informations();
res[1] = cercle.Informations();
res[2] = rectangle.Surface().ToString();
res[3] = cercle.Surface().ToString();
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't know than we can use ToString when we insert a value on array.

So i resolved my problem. Thanks :)